# Prevent iframe / section from reloading when whole page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Maybe it is a bit of a silly question, but I am wondering if it is possible to prevent an iframe from reloading when a whole page reloads.

I have made an application in ASP.NET. I have one page, and on that page there is a form, a tabel and a section with an iframe. In that section I can "upload" an pdf file, and this pdf file is shown in an iframe. like this:

```
<section class="invoice_file">
<div class="invoice_file_header">
    <input id="upload_button" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
</div>
<iframe id="upload_factuur" type="application/pdf" width="696" height="433"></iframe>
</section>
```

With my javascript code, the pdf file displays in my iframe (most of the times):

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#upload_factuur')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

The idea is that on that pdf file, there is information. This information will be taken over and put into the form. When I submit the form, the data will show in the tabel. But to do this, the page reloads (redirect). And so does my section with the pdf. Thereby the pdf file disapears and I should upload the file once again

So is there a way to prevent a section or iframe to reload when the whole page reloads.

Comment: If the outer page reloads, the `<iframe>` is re-created. There's nothing you can do about that without re-architecting the entire thing (so that you can load *parts* of the outer page without reloading the while thing).

Comment: There is no way to do this. But, you can use some JS and push data via AJAX and then re-render page content without redirect.

Comment: @Pointy, allright, I already thought so, but I could always ask

Comment: @DmitryVolokh, is that easy, can you explain how?

Comment: @kareltjeknak it could be easy, could be not. depends on your application/experience. Try to google 'ajax login'

Comment: @DmitryVolokh the page i'm working in has already an id

Comment: technically you can submit form and update specific part of the page using ajax without touching iframe, another approach would be to use some persistence mechanism (session for example) to store iframe url  and check it on page reload. There is more to that but this is the basic idea.

Comment: For an asp solution you could try isolating the form portion in an  `<asp:UpdatePanel>` this way when you submit the form only the portion of the page that has the form inputs and the table get updated.  The iframe and the upload pdf portion should not be affected.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a redirect so I'm not sure if this will work.  If you mean that you "redirect" to the same page due to the nature of a postback then this could help achieve your goal

```
...
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"
        UpdateMode="Conditional" 
        ChildrenAsTriggers="True">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
          <!-- All your Form fields-->
          <asp:Button ID="your submit button" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
        </div>
        <table id="yourtable">
        </table>
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <section class="invoice_file">
      <div class="invoice_file_header">
        <input id="upload_button" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
      </div>
      <iframe id="upload_factuur" type="application/pdf" width="696" height="433">
      </iframe>
    </section>
  </form>
</body>
...
```

If you are not familiar with UpdatePanels please see these links:

- [UpdatePanel Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel(v=vs.140).aspx)
- [Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)